# For one employee, In time and Out time should be returned on one line

Tags: sql, oracle, over-clause

```
select 
    compcode, emplcode, attndate, costcode,
    decode(shiftflg, 'I', readtime) INTIME,
    decode(shiftflg, 'O', readtime) OUTTIME
from
    ecatnrec
where  
    emplcode = 'RF025'
order by 
    emplcode;
```

[image]

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` AND `MAX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select compcode, emplcode, attndate, costcode,
       max(case when shiftflg = 'I' then readtime end) as INTIME,
       max(case when shiftflg = 'O' then readtime end) as OUTTIME
from ecatnrec
where  emplcode = 'RF025'
group by compcode, emplcode, attndate, costcode
order by emplcode;
```

This assumes that there is at most on "I" and one "O" row for unique values of the `group by` keys.